# How to map an Array of arrays to object like property and value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im new to javaScript and react..

i have an array consisting of objects. I need to display this array in a AG GRID so what im tring here to map this to array of flat obj.

**NOTE: I cannot use jQuery..**

below is my array (full code is in codepen, please check the link)

```
let realData = [
  [
    {
      "key" : "flightNumber" ,
      "label": "Flight Number",
      "value": "EK 131",
      "value-type": "String",
      "order" : 1
    },
    {        
      "key" : "flightId",
      "label": "flightId",
      "value": "1223434",
      "value-type": "String",
      "order" : 2,
      "isId": true
    },
    {

      "key": "CallSign",
      "label": "callSign",
      "value": "123",
      "value-type": "String",
      "order" : 3
    },
  ]
]
```

what i want the result is

```
let newArray = [
    {flightNumber: 'EK 131', flightType: 'A', lastUpdate: '11223232', destOrig: 'BEY', sibtSobt: '12121333123', CallSign: '123'},
    {flightNumber: 'EK 132', flightType: 'D', lastUpdate: '11334455', destOrig: 'DEST', sibtSobt: '1234443222', CallSign: '443'}
]
```

please help

[link](https://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/qxJxEq?editors=0012)

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried ? I recommend you take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: please see this https://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/qxJxEq?editors=0012

Comment: Please include all important information directly into the question. See the help center for question requirements!

Comment: There are some keys that are expected to be values? There are value and keys that didn't exist in JSON but do in result? `sibtSobt`?

Comment: @zer00ne i cannot put all the data code in the editer.. so i put tham in codepen and attach the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below working code...

```
const newData = [];

realData.forEach((val) => {
  let obj = {};
  val.forEach(v => obj[v.key] = v.value);
  newData.push(obj);
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map the new objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for a single object.

```js
var data = [[{ key: "flightNumber", label: "Flight Number", value: "EK 131", "value-type": "String", order: 1 }, { key: "flightId", label: "flightId", value: "1223434", "value-type": "String", order: 2, isId: true }, { key: "CallSign", label: "callSign", value: "123", "value-type": "String", order: 3 }]],
    result = data.map(a => Object.assign(...a.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. but please see the full array in codepen.

Answer (score 2):

You can `reduce` each array key/value pair into an object :

```js
const arrays = [
[
    {
      "key" : "flightNumber" ,
      "label": "Flight Number",
      "value": "EK 131",
      "value-type": "String",
      "order" : 1
    },
    {        
      "key" : "flightId",
      "label": "flightId",
      "value": "1223434",
      "value-type": "String",
      "order" : 2,
      "isId": true
    },
    {

      "key": "CallSign",
      "label": "callSign",
      "value": "123",
      "value-type": "String",
      "order" : 3
    }
]
];

const objects = arrays.map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  acc[cur.key] = cur.value;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(objects);
```