# Concatenate objects inside an array of multiple array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert an array from this:

```
const categories = [{
  name: 'category1',
  items: [
    {itemId: 1, name: 'Item1'},
    {itemId: 2, name: 'Item2'},
  ],
}, {
  name: 'category2',
  items: [
    {itemId: 3, name: 'Item3'},
    {itemId: 4, name: 'Item4'},
  ],
}];
```

to look something like this:

```
const result = [ 
  { itemId: 1, name: 'Item1' }, 
  { itemId: 2, name: 'Item2' }, 
  { itemId: 3, name: 'Item3' }, 
  { itemId: 4, name: 'Item4' },
];
```

Any helps would be amazing! Thank you.

Comment: You can use `categories.map(e => e.items).flat()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map an Array of arrays to object like property and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987141/how-to-map-an-array-of-arrays-to-object-like-property-and-value)

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes as it is a very localized duplicate of another question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a environment that supports nodejs over 11.0.0

You can use this piece of code:

```
categories.flatMap(({items}) => items)
```

Check the compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

But if you're not in this kind of environment you could use this piece of code:

```
const result = []
const categories = [ { name: "category1"
        , items: 
          [ { itemId: 1, name: "Item1" } 
          , { itemId: 2, name: "Item2" } 
          ] 
        } 
      , { name: "category2"
        , items: 
          [ { itemId: 3, name: "Item3" } 
          , { itemId: 4, name: "Item4" } 
      ] } ]
categories.map(({items}) => items).forEach(arr => result.push(...arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
categories.reduce((result, item) => {
  result.push(...item.items);
  return result;
}, []);
```